# What is the difference between a Headless Fragment and a Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, headless-fragments

#### Service

A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

#### Headless Fragment

Fragments can be used without defining a user interface.  It is recommended to use headless fragments for your background processing.

What is the difference here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`Service`s are given higher priority than `Activity`s at the process-level. When memory is low, the Android system will prioritize `Service`s over `Activity`s, making `Service`s the ideal option for long-running tasks. See the article titled [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) for more information.

Also, when you state the following in your original post:

> Fragments can be used without defining a user interface. It is recommended to use headless fragments for your background processing.

Where are you quoting this from? I agree with the first sentence, but the second sentence is too general. For short-running tasks (such as performing HTTP requests, etc.), headless fragments work fine. However, for performing long-running background processing (such as downloading a very large file, etc.) a headless fragment may not be what you want. For example, if you used a headless fragment to perform a long-running task and the user clicked the "back button", this will cause both the `Activity` and its headless `Fragment` to be destroyed.

To summarize, a service is a background component that exists independent of an `Activity`, meaning that it can continue to run in the background even if the `Activity` which started the service is destroyed. On the other hand, a headless fragment will always have an associated parent `Activity`. If the `Activity` that hosts the fragment is destroyed by the system, then the fragment will have to be killed as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got the headless fragment information from the following link because there was no Android documentation on headless fragments.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments1

Comment: Nice and very useful explanation Alex.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood Services are given higher priority than Activities at the process-level I have read the link you have provided but does not found any information like this.

Answer (score 36):

*Generally speaking*:

**Headless Fragments** are meant to **encapsulate data**. Headless fragments are meant to encapsulate data which can be shared between various application components (since they can exist independently of a UI component).

**Services** are meant to **encapsulate processing**. They are more independent (and therefore also more heavy-weight, resource wise) than fragments are; they sit at a different level of abstraction and can last longer, in a system.

**There is overlap between the two.**

Comment: I think , this one is the more precise.

Answer (score 3):

Headless fragment- fragment with no ui, basically used for storing large size object

---

Service - its long running task start by android, we can set priority to service even application get finished service will not stop unless its work get completed.