# when to use fragments without UI?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I used to use `async tasks` for background tasks but later found out that `services` are recommended instead as they have longer life.

Now, reading about `fragments` I found out you can use ***fragments without ui*** to run background tasks.

I have seen this: [Application threads vs Service threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633334/application-threads-vs-service-threads)

which only talks about the life-time difference between threads and services.

*am confused here!* when planning to use background tasks what are the appropriate times when to use **services**, **fragments without UI** or the **normal java Threads**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use case for a Fragment with no UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531648/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-fragment-with-no-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Fragment can persist through device configuration changes like screen rotation. Because an Activity will be destroyed and recreated when a configuration change happens, it is  difficult to design one that will keep track of a THREAD or ASYNCTASK . On the other hand, the system takes care of reattaching a persistent Fragment to the proper Activity at the other end  of the configuration change. You would still be using a THREAD  or ASYNCTASK, only now the Fragment is holding it instead.

Comment: So just to be clear are you saying fragment can persist after screen rotation, this seems to contradict with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799759/what-is-the-difference-between-a-headless-fragment-and-a-service-in-android