# Why AsyncTask are not prefered for Long Running Operations

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have read the two reasons/issue mentioned on:
(Please read two reason on below link)
[Android AsyncTask for Long Running Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797550/android-asynctask-for-long-running-operations/)
1. "If you start an AsyncTask inside an Activity and you rotate the device, the Activity will be destroyed and a new instance will be created. But the AsyncTask will not die":
**Lets suppose i have set the orientation of my activity to Portrait. Will this issue still be there?**

2. Memory leak issue: 
inner class will hold an invisible reference on its outer class instance : the Activity.
**What if i am not using Inner AsyncTask instead created separate class. Also if i use weak reference.**

Comment: If u set orientation of activity to portrait, the activity wont be destroyed if u rotate device, So no new instance.

Comment: @AkshayBhat can you pls tell "Why AsyncTask are not prefered for Long Running Operations"

Comment: @rathee ashish isn't it already explained to you in your own link your prived?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AsyncTask for Long Running Operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797550/android-asynctask-for-long-running-operations)

Comment: As per my knowledge AsyncTasks are designed for network Operations and android developers mentioned not to use it for asynctask for long operations. Services comes handy when u want to do long running operations.

Comment: @rathee ashish, I recommend to use `AsyncTask` in `Service`.

Comment: @mjp66 have you read the points i have higlighted carefully

Comment: @AkshayBhat i too want to know the reason why asynctask should not be used for long running process

Comment: In a long running process, android os may kill your activity for some reason like memory shortage etc. So android os prefers activities to destroy first instead of services. This is the reason we use services for long running operation.

Comment: @AkshayBhat That doesn't really help you, because usually a service shares the event thread with the activity that started it (unless the service is in another process). In that the service is actually synchronous. That's also why e.g. `IntentService` spawns a worker thread to handle requests.

Comment: @rathee ashish post your code ....so evry buddy can justify your issue .

Answer (score 4):

The issues you mention arise only when life-cycle of AsyncTask is not handled properly, mainly from lack of understanding of how they work.

AsyncTask is a wrapper for running code on a separate thread. It is similar to plain Java's `Runnable` submitted to `ExecutorService`, with additional features of "pre" and "post" hooks to be run on main thread. So, its basically an enhanced version of `Thread`, `Runnable` and `Handler` setup.

By default AsycTask's share a single thread and hence not advised for long running tasks. Because when a single background thread is shared by many tasks, a long running task may block others. However, AsycTask can also run on a custom `Executor`, removing such restrictions of a shared worker thread.

All that means that AsyncTask's own design doesn't restrict its usage for long running tasks.

You can have a background `Service` run some continuous processing using  AsyncTasks on a separate `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

You can have a `Fragment` load latest news using an AsyncTask and when Fragment's `onDestroy()` is called, you cancel the task, since its no longer meaningful.

Hence the answer to "how long and AsyncTask should run", entirely depends upon the usage context.

Comment: Android documentation says: "syncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask."    But why?

Comment: @ratheeashish That is because "by default" all tasks are scheduled on single thread and a long task may deprive others of a chance to run. But AsyncTask also has a feature to run on your "custom" executor, with which you can run it independent of other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting the orientation will work because locking to portrait means no orientation change, meaning no lifecycle re-creation because of this. However if an activity is paused for a long time it can still be destroyed so this is not a good way to make sure this works 100%. You could instead try [a service or a headless fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799759/what-is-the-difference-between-a-headless-fragment-and-a-service-in-android).
2. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297378/weakreference-asynctask-pattern-in-android?rq=1) post, having a weak reference will solve the memory issue

Comment: 2. Inner class will hold an invisible reference on its outer class instance : But if i use Separate class for Async task will Memory leak issue still there?

Comment: See this post for having weak reference and memory leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297378/weakreference-asynctask-pattern-in-android?rq=1

Comment: to point 1: If you pause your app or stack some views, the underlying activities could be destroyed by the system (e.g. if some memory is needed). Because of that your view will be recreated, if you reopen the view. You got a leak, if our AsyncTask is not well-designed.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks, I'll add it to the post

Answer (score 1):

Additional problem of `AsyncTask`: **losing your results**.

Yes, you said:

> Lets suppose i have set the orientation of my activity to Portrait.
>   Will this issue still be there?

But, `Activity` could be recreated not only 'cause rotation. For example, if there is no enough resources in system, operation system can destroy your Activity.

So, for long running operations there is high risk that `AsyncTask` will have an invalid reference to its Activity in `onPostExecute()` after Activity recreation.

Another problem: **parallelism**.

```
new AsyncTask1().execute();
new AsyncTask2().execute();
```

Will these two tasks run at the same time or will AsyncTask2 start when AsyncTask1 is finished?
Well... It depends on the **API level**.

And aboud API level...

**Before API 1.6 (Donut)**: the tasks were executed serially. This means a task won't start before a previous task is finished.

**API 1.6 to API 2.3 (Gingerbread)**: the Android developers team changed AsyncTasks to make possibility to start them in parallel on a separate worker thread.

**API 3.0 (Honeycomb)**: the AsyncTasks where executed serially again. Of course the Android team provided the possibility to let them run parallel. This is done by the method `executeOnExecutor(Executor)`. Check out the API documentation for more information on this.

Comment: If Activity is in foreground then there are more then activity would be the last to destroyed(THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND)... where as async task uses workerthread with(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND).....     In that case no need to worry.... async task should be killed itself also.....Not sure about it....please correct if wrong

Comment: @ratheeashish but anyway. Even if your Task will be killed carefully, your Task will be stopped. If you will use Service, even if Activity will be destroyed your Task will continue work.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask have following drawback.

**1. Memory leak** :- In inner class as well in seprate class you provide reference of your activity to AsyncTask for callback in both case AsyncTask will not release the reference of activity for GC which cause memory leak.

**2. GC :-** If a AsyncTask is running although the calling activity is destroyed it will restrict the GC to not run till it will not finish its process.

**3. On Orintation** change activity recreate as Asynchtask will running in background and when it finish its operation it will try to update UI which cause IllegalStateException as activity is not attached to window.

So its better if you use Service for long running background process instead of AsyncTask.

Comment: 1. For Memory Leak: If i use Weak reference, will reference problem still be there?

Comment: 3. On Orientation: I have set the fixed orientation. "IllegalStateException" will not be there?

Comment: 2. Let's suppose you are uploading image in async task.... its a good thing that it is running even after activity is destroyed?

Comment: 1. If you can use Week Reference it is good practice but you have to be carefull here now you need to check the activity reference is null or not before passing the result else you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: 3. If you fix the Orientaion of activity it is you limiting the functionality if it is allowed in your case then no issue.

Comment: Ok lets suppose i am checking activity reference is null... in that case....can i use async for long running process

Comment: 2. If you don't need callback of that uploaded image then their may be no issue but in case of callback definitely it is not a best practice you may have duplicate images on server in this case.

Comment: If Still you are checking reference is null then you didn't receive callback on activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many superstitions around this topic, it's hard to know where to start. `AsyncTask` is just a small piece of sugar around a standard task queue, using it or not using it does not make much difference in comparison to other things.

For example the problem of orientation change is NOT real. You can start an `AsyncTask` when the activity starts for the first time and simply not start it the next time around. (and remember that other changes in configuration can also restart your activity).

The weak references are a total overkill and will probably get you nowhere. You either need a reference to the current activity (and then the weak reference won't work) or not (and then, simply don't hold any reference).

The most important, and missing from your question, is what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Think about someone answering their phone while your application is running, and going back to it after some time. And then try to answer questions like:
 - are the results from 15 minutes ago relevant? Or will the task be restarted?
 - how about 6 hours ago?
 - will something bad happen if the background task is interrupted?
 - does user expect the task to be finished? (did he press "OK" and just waited for a confirmation to appear?).

And *then* you can ask a more precise question. `AsyncTask` can be used in any scenario, but usually it's simpler not to use it than to use it correctly.